# spark-submit: process never dies

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running PySpark analysis on some data. This is the first time I carry out data analysis using Spark, therefore there are multiple details on the workflow of PySpark that confuses me.

The one related to this question is: the process generated by my

```
nohup spark-submit test.py 1>output &
```

never dies, even after the all results are collected. The following command

```
ps aux | grep python
```

contains this process after the job is done

```
myusername 7216 0.1 0.0 626924 53364 pts/1  Sl 17:14 0:01 python /path/to/test.py
```

As a result, I need to manually

```
kill -15 7216
```

and the world is saved. Can I save the world without killing anything?

Or is it just a zombie process that I have to kill afterward?

Comment: run kill with sudo privileges

Comment: @eliasah Maybe my question is not clear enough. Can I write a PySpark script that stops itself when results has been collected? I don't want to look up pid and kill everytime. It's too much work for the lazy me:P

Comment: Sure! How are you launching your job thought as well?

Comment: @eliasah It is on the fourth line of my question:D

Comment: `nohup spark-summit test.py 1>output &` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92561/discussion-between-eliasah-and-mai).